# Sub menus "mouseover" disabled in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

My menu is mobile responsive in the sense that it resizes and drops to a hamburger menu on mobile devices where applicable.

My issue is that the menu also features a sub-menu element that also should be visible on mobile devices but since there is no mouseover on mobile devices, the "tap" takes the viewer to the menu url configured in the main menu nav area.

I've attempted to add the   `visibility: visible;` element to any sub-menu reference in the CSS but when you tap the dropdown on an iPad tablet for example does nothing except take me to the same URL configured in the main menu element that is tapped.  How do I overcome this and display this submenu?

Sample URL: http://www.goroyalshell.net/

Comment: This is probably not super helpful but I just avoid having a parent menu linking anywhere - links are only applied to child menus. If you can't do that, could you use media queries to set display:none on the parent link?  You'd have to still show the link text of course which would need a separate element hidden on larger displays, again using media queries.  All a bit of a fudge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to add event listener from JavaScript like this to catch touch event?

```
document.getElementById('#yourTabId').addEventListener('touchstart', function(ev) { 
    //here set your functionality for dropdown 
});
```